# SBCL Built executable: "When attempting to set the slot's value to XXX (SETF of SLOT-VALUE), the slot YYY is missing from the object"?

Tags: common-lisp, executable, sbcl, clos

It's completely fine to run `#'cl-state-machine-examples/tamagochi:run`,

But generated executable signals `SIMPLE-ERROR` like this:

Built: https://github.com/ageldama/cl-state-machine/releases/tag/fail-sbcl-slot-value

And I get:

```
$ ./tamagochi.exe

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005384C3}>:
  When attempting to set the slot's value to 5 (SETF of SLOT-VALUE), the slot
  MONEY is missing from the object
  #<CL-STATE-MACHINE-EXAMPLES/TAMAGOCHI::TAMAGOCHI-STATUS {1001B7B9B3}>.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit from the current thread.

((:METHOD SLOT-MISSING (T T T T)) #<unused argument> #<CL-STATE-MACHINE-EXAMPLES/TAMAGOCHI::TAMAGOCHI-STATUS {1001B7B9B3}> MONEY SETF 5) [fast-method]
0]
```

using:

- Uname -a : Linux arch-desktop 5.3.11-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 12
  Nov 2019 22:19:48 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- https://github.com/ageldama/cl-state-machine/releases/tag/fail-sbcl-slot-value

Both for:
  - sbcl-1.5.0-x86-64-linux AND sbcl-1.5.9-x86-64-linux/

Build log is:

```
This is SBCL 1.5.9, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
WARNING: redefining UIOP/PACKAGE:FIND-PACKAGE* in DEFUN
...CUT...
WARNING: redefining UIOP/BACKWARD-DRIVER:VERSION-COMPATIBLE-P in DEFUN
[undoing binding stack and other enclosing state... done]
[performing final GC... done]
[defragmenting immobile space... (fin,inst,fdefn,code,sym)=1062+946+18321+18719+25423... done]
[saving current Lisp image into /home/jhyun/P/cl-state-machine/tamagochi.exe:
writing 0 bytes from the read-only space at 0x50000000
writing 432 bytes from the static space at 0x50100000
writing 27852800 bytes from the dynamic space at 0x1000000000
writing 2011136 bytes from the immobile space at 0x50300000
writing 12144640 bytes from the immobile space at 0x52100000
done]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that your `keyword->symbol` function interns into the wrong package, because the `read` in there is executed from a different one:

```
(defun keyword->symbol (kw-or-symbol)
  (with-input-from-string (s-in (string kw-or-symbol))
    (read s-in)))
```

I'd use `intern` to create the symbol:

```
(defun keyword->symbol (kw-or-symbol)
  (intern (symbol-name kw-or-symbol)
          #.*package*))
```

The `#.*package*` construct gives the value of `*package*` at read time, i. e. when the function form above was read.

Comment: YES! It fixed, thank you so much! <https://github.com/ageldama/sbcl-exe-slot-value>

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that keywords _are_ symbols in Common Lisp.

Comment: Sure, I know that. KWs are symbols in `keyword`-package. But I couldn't get `(slot-value (make-instance 'point-2d) :y)` <-- this. (``y` would be correct, right?)

Comment: @Jong-HyoukYun: I didn't mean that it could be done differently, I just wanted to point out that the name `keyword->symbol` might seem slightly _strange_.  I don't have a better name, though.

Comment: it's ok. same here, don't come up with better naming too.